# How to search recursively in a directory for different files?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a `x.tar` file in directory `/a`. After untaring `x.tar` I got the following result:

```
cust/
cust/01/
cust/01/INFENG/
cust/01/INFENG/scr/
cust/01/INFENG/scr/test.scr
cust/01/INFENG/SQL/
cust/01/INFENG/SQL/test.sql
cust/01/INFENG/MRT/
```

The directory `cust` was created in `/a` with the given directory structure. Now what I need to do is take safe of the existing files present in the path and then replace them with the files un-tared in `/a`. So how can I achieve this through a shell script?

For exmple, I have to take safe of `cust/01/INFENG/scr/test.scr` (existing) before replacing it with the file I got by untaring the tar file in `/a`.

I am using `ksh`.

Comment: After `untar`ing the file `test.scr` is in `/a/cust/01/INFENG/scr/test.scr` ..whats the path of original `test.scr` ?

Comment: @heemayl /app/cust/01/INFENG/scr/test.scr

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
a_files=( $(find /path/to/a/ -type f) )

for file in "${a_files[@]}"; do
        mv "/path/to/app${file##*a}" "/path/to/app${file##*a}.bak"
        mv "$file" "/path/to/app${file##*a}"
done
```

If `a/` and `app/` are in same directory e.g. `/home/user/{a,app}`, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
a_files=( $(find /home/user/a/ -type f) )

for file in "${a_files[@]}"; do
        mv "${file%%a/*}app${file##*/a}" "${file%%a/*}app${file##*/a}.bak"
        mv "$file" "${file%%a/*}app${file##*/a}"
done
```

This will at first take the backup of the files of `/home/user/app/` as `.bak` extension and then replace the original files with the files from `/home/user/a`.

Comment: Just one question: What does `{file##*a}` do?

Comment: `{file##*a}` is bash parameter expansion pattern..it will delete the longest match from left until `/a`....so if the full path to the file is `/home/user/a/file.scr` then it will remove `/home/user/a` ..check [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: `ksh` also supports this..so will work the same way

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
cd /a || exit

find . -type f |
    while read FILE
    do
        TARGET="/app/$FILE"
        test -f "$TARGET" && cp -fp "$TARGET" "$TARGET.bak"
        mv "$FILE" "$TARGET"
    done
```